# How to implement asynchronous service call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to call my server asynchronously.

My code is as below:-

```
function GetSynchronousJSONResponse(url, postData) {
var xmlhttp = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
if (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
xmlhttp.send(postData);
var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
return responseText;
}
```

But service call gives "Bad Request" error.
Please help

Comment: show you postData values

Comment: Why not use jQuery? It will save you a lot of trouble in the future..

Comment: You did read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()), didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add content type in your request.
please add below line and try again
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

function GetSynchronousJSONResponse(URL,postData) 
{

```
        $.ajax({

           url : URL,

           type : "POST",

           data : JSON.stringify(postData),//if required

           contentType : 'application/json',

           success : function(data) {}
   })
}
```

**you can Try this .....................**

Comment: Don't call this function `GetSynchronous…`!

Comment: Yes, in the first line of your answer.